# Validate mixed content containing exactly one text node with RNC

Tags: xml, validation, relaxng, relaxng-compact

I'm trying to validate a mixed content element which should contain exactly one text node. Eg, this should validate:

```
<corner description="ff models, bc RC; high temperature,high vdd">
  <modelSection>fff_pre</modelSection>
  <var value="high">temperature</var>
  <var value="high">vdd</var>
  fff_pre_Thi_Vhi_Vhi
</corner>
```

but this should not:

```
<corner description="ff models, bc RC; high temperature,high vdd">
  <modelSection>fff_pre</modelSection>
  <var value="high">temperature</var>
  <var value="high">vdd</var>
  <!-- no text, invalid! -->
</corner>
```

I tried

```
corner = element corner {
  description,
  (
    modelSection
    & var+
    & xsd:string
  )
}
```

(where `description`, `modelSection` and `var` are previously defined) but while validating the first example above rnv reports a "text not allowed" error for fff_pre_Thi_Vhi_Vhi. Substituting `& text` for `& xsd:string` validates a textless `<corner>`, which I don't want. Feels like this must be simple and I'm overlooking something... Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try to run `jing` with your schema (after adding the missing bits and converting from rnc to rng), I get this error:

```
/tmp/t2/test.rng:4:28: error: interleave of "string" or "data" element
```

This error correspond to the part of the rng that defines the contents of the `corner` element.

This suggest to me that you are running smack dab into the limitation specified in [Section 7.2](http://relaxng.org/spec-20011203.html#string-sequences) of the Relax NG spec. In your case, you are trying to have an element which will accept as children other elements and a `data` pattern. The spec does not allow it.

If you are generating the XML, you could solve the issue by generating a structure like this:

```
<corner description="ff models, bc RC; high temperature,high vdd">
  <modelSection>fff_pre</modelSection>
  <var value="high">temperature</var>
  <var value="high">vdd</var>
  <data>fff_pre_Thi_Vhi_Vhi</data>
</corner>
```

With a rnc like this:

```
corner = element corner {
  description,
  (
    modelSection
    & var+
    & data
  )
}

data = element data { xsd:string { minLength = "1" } }
```

I used `data` as the name of the element but I would want something more specific than this in a final solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `xsd:string` and setting a minimum length of 1? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709260/1712389 for an answer in RNG.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you see in the initial problem I'd tried xsd:string and unfortunately adding minLength doesn't change its validity. I think Louis is right that this particular construct isn't allowed by RNG.

Comment: Right. I thought the issue was just with defining a non-zero-length string.